# Best factor for determining the bettering of CPU

Tags: cpu, speed, cpu-speed, clockspeed

First of all, if my English is not good please pardon me.

Now the problem; when comparing many CPUs with each other, which factor is the best one? For example, there are many various types, like, core to due, dual core, pentium, core ix, and many many other flavors.
When I'm at this bad situation I save myself by choosing the best one by their HZ unit .
For example, when there are many varous CPUs I say most powerful one is that has bigger frequency unit. 2.66GHZ<2.88GHZ.
Is it a true solution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare the performance of different CPUs by their clock frequency. A modern i7 will do much more in a clock cycle than a Pentium P4.
The only way to find out which CPU is better for your purposes is to search for a benchmark where someone has actually run something on the CPUs and compared the performance.

Answer (score 0):

For some insight, have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/423596/multi-core-cpu-can-i-say-i-have-a-3x2-1ghz-6-3ghz-cpu?rq=1)
 - in **theory** `the faster the CPU clock`, the `more cores` and to some extent `hyperthreading`
will enable more work to be done in parallel.

But there are bottlenecks, as in accessing memory and also hardisks, which most often only have ONE communication channel (road).

Also: The software you use MUST be capable of handing out tasks to multiple CPU's
 - this is most often not the case, and it does not happen by "magic".